# Get elements from line of integers java

Tags: java

I have the following

```
10 30 15
89 1 3
65 48 12
```

I would like to have each of those numbers in each line to different lists.

For example

```
list1 contains 10 30 15
list2 contains 89 1 3
list3 contains 65 48 12
```

I have tried the following but without sucess... Could someone help me out?

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        list1.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        list2.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        list3.add(sc.nextInt());
    }

    sc.close();
```

Comment: always will be 3 numbers?

Comment: No, they it will be n numbers. I put 3 as an example

Comment: I think the question was, always 3 lines ?

Comment: Yes always 3 lines, with n numbers in each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split the next line using space as the delimiter(if that is always the case) then use Integer.parseInt() on those tokens to add elements on the list.

```
public static void main(String... args){
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] strArray;

    if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        strArray = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+");
        for(String item : strArray)
            list1.add(Integer.parseInt(item));
    }
    if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        strArray = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+");
        for(String item : strArray)
            list2.add(Integer.parseInt(item));
    }
    if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        strArray = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+");
        for(String item : strArray)
            list3.add(Integer.parseInt(item));
    }

    sc.close();
    System.out.println(list1);
    System.out.println(list2);
    System.out.println(list3);
}
```

Console:

```
//input
10 30 15
89 1 3
65 48 12

   //output
  [10, 30, 15]
  [89, 1, 3]
  [65, 48, 12]
```

This is assuming there are always 3 lines of input(as OP stated) and no bad input.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have 3 lines you could just create a String per line and a List of integer per line. Then you get a line in a String, split the string using space as delimiter. Finally you parse the integers and add them to your list.

Here the code for one line :

```
String line1 = sc.nextLine();
List<int> list1 = new ArrayList<int>();
String[] ints = line1.split(" ");
for(String s : ints) {
    list1.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you use scanner, you can use the method `nextInt()` and `hasNextInt()`

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        list1.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
    }
    sc.nextLine();
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        list2.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
    }
    sc.nextLine();
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        list3.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
    }

    sc.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Each line needs to be splited and then each part of the split needs to be parsed:

```
Set<List<Integer>> myListSet = new HashSet<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
            Arrays
                .stream(sc.nextLine().split("\\s+"))
                .map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
                .forEach(intList::add);
            myListSet.add(intList);
        }
        sc.close();
```

`myListSet` now contains many lists and each list has n integer Numbers